# Date variable do not have method addDays

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two `TextBoxes` in which I am getteing 2 dates and getting array of dates between those two. I have a code

```
$(".txtto").change(function () {
                var dates = new Array();
                var dateto = new Date();
                var datefrom = new Date();
                dateto.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
                datefrom.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
                dateto = $(this).val();
                datefrom = $(".datefrom").val();
                while (datefrom <= dateto) {
                    dates.push(new Date(datefrom));
                    datefrom = datefrom.addDays(1);
                }
            });
```

But it is giving an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object 18/11/2014 has no method 'addDays'`

`18/11/2014` is input date.

**Edit 1:**

Meanwhile I tried this

```
$(".txtto").change(function () {
                var dates = new Array();
                var dateto = new Date();
                var datefrom = new Date();
                dateto.setDate($(this).val());
                dateto.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
                console.log(dateto);
                datefrom.setDate($(".datefrom").val());
                while (datefrom <= dateto) {
                    dates.push(new Date(datefrom));
                    datefrom = datefrom.setDate(datefrom.getDate() + 1);
                }
            });
```

but `console.log(dateto);` outputs invalid date :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no method like `addDays()` - you need to use `setDate()`:

```
datefrom.setDate(now3.getDate() - 4);
```

Use `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
dateto.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Just Change Your Loop like this

```
while (datefrom <= dateto) {

                  dates.push(new Date(datefrom));
                  datefrom = new Date(datefrom.setDate(datefrom.getDate() + 1));
                }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ms9oz80a/)

REFER DOCS
[DATE documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: same issue `Object 13/11/2014 has no method 'getDate' ` I think I have a different problem..

Comment: check this values `alert(datefrom )`,`alert(dateto)` may be undefined ??

Comment: I used code in my original question and changed loop as u suggested but its giving error `Object 20/11/2014 has no method 'getDate' `

Comment: Actually it giving `invalid date` when I print `new Date(datefrom)`

Comment: @Imad refer jsfiddle now added

Comment: Its different fiddle sir, plz confirm.

Comment: Fiddle is always awesome, but it gives same errors if I format dates.

Comment: My textbox value is in `dd/MM/yyyy` format. I am entering `11/12/2014` but javascript is reading it as `Dec 11 .....` but it is `Nov 12 ....`.. this is why I am converting..